# solr sort,i want Specify a particular document at the first

Tags: solr

solr sort,i want Specify a particular document at the first

for example:

Results :**5,2,3,1**

I want **2** at the first ,Other sorted in accordance with the rules

**2,1,3,5**

how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two ways you can try to tackle this using Solr.

The first is to use the [QueryElevationComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent). This lets you define the top results at index time. As suggested in the documentation, this is good for placing sponsored results or popular documents at the top of the search results. The potential downside is that you have to be able to identify those documents at index time and not at query time.

The other approach is to boost the desired documents at query time using the [bq parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29). To boost document 435, you would do something like this:

```
...&bq=id:435^10
```

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches give you absolute control over the order of the results.

The solution provided by Riking would certainly do the job if you don't mind processing the results after performing the search. Another approach you could consider is to add a field to your Solr schema that defines a display order or priority. You can then sort on that field to get the desired sort order.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Solr 3.1 or later, you can [sort by a function query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort). The [map](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#map) function is useful for this.

```
sort=map(field_name,5,5,0) asc
```

In the above, `field_name` is the name of the field you want to sort by, `5` is the value you want to push to the front and `0` must be replaced with some number that you know is less than all other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Call the builtin sort() function, then shift the desired element to the front.

Pseudocode, in case you do not have a builtin method to shift it to the front:

```
tmp = desired;
int dIndex = array.indexOf(desired);
for(i=dIndex-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    array[i+1] = array[i]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you use standart query (not dismax) add "OR id:2^1000" to you query. Like this:

```
q=(text:lalala AND author:Bob) OR id:2^1000
```

that will place document with ID=2 at the top of results.